# Direct to .html instead of .php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

My .htaccess file currently has -

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Since I have two files (login.html and login.php), when I do /login, it automatically goes to the php.

In a javascript file, I have it redirecting to /login, but I need it to redirect to login.html, not login.php. How do I do that without doing `/login.html` because I still want to hide the extensions from the  website url. Similarly, how would I redirect to either sites without the extensions? Is it possible or do I need to create different names for them.

Comment: you can do it by redirecting the request with php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

here you are how to do it

Comment: Have you try to swap htaccess rule order? html in the top and php bottom

Comment: I don't understand, in the Javascript file, who exactly are you hiding the extension from?

Comment: you should try to find out if this request is from javascript in your htaccess file, to do this I think you should set an parameter that you could detected it is a javascript request, for example you can set the url in you javascript code as index.html?type=js and then you should rewrite your rules in htaccess file,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're essentially stripping the extension, you would need different file names for them.